# Where should Adobe Analytics' non-standard variables be set within Adobe DTM?

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm using Adobe Analytics as a tool within DTM. I had an issue which needed to have a particular variable be set to false `s.useForcedLinkTracking=false;` but the issue is I'm not sure of the proper place to set this in DTM? I tried within the tool set-up section for Adobe Analytics but the value was still true when the page compiled. The only place I got it to work properly was in the Adobe Analytics section within the "Custom Page Code" for a global page load rule.

So is there a proper place where variables like this should be set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Adobe is hosting your App Measurement file you can run your configuration variables (including calls to do_plugins) within the custom page code section of your Adobe Analytics tool. This is "global code" that will execute any time Adobe Analytics is loaded.

This approach also helps you consolidate calls to plugins and custom code in a single place without having to customize the App Measurement file itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should place this in the custom s_code file (if you're not using a managed core library from Adobe) or in the custom page code within the tool config. Adding some console logging to see the full order of execution will help tremendously.

Comment: I tried this initially in the "Custom Page Code" for the tool and in the app measurement library but the variable was not being changed. It was still showing as true. We are sourcing the dtm code from the CDN unless it is in production where we then source from our own servers.

Comment: s.useForcedLinkTracking=false; Should be set where your other config vars are set (ie s.linkTrackVars, etc)